# JDBC Oracle Ref Cursor to display contents of a table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, cursors

I'm trying to print the contents of employees table through java using jdbc.
I created the following package and function with ref cursor.

```
create or replace
package packagename as
type ref_cursor is ref cursor;
end;
/

create or replace function get_employees
return packagename.ref_cursor
as employees_cursor packagename.ref_cursor;
begin
open employees_cursor for
select * from employees;
return employees_cursor;
end;
/
```

And my java code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class getemployees {

public static void main (String args []) throws SQLException {
try
{

    //Connecting to Oracle server
    OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@castor.cc.fsu.edu:1521:acad111");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");

    //Prepare to call stored procedure:
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("begin ? := packagename.get_employees(); end;");

   //register the out parameter (the first parameter)
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);


    // execute and retrieve the result set
    cs.execute();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject(1);

    // print the results
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" +
            rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3));
    }

    //close the result set, statement, and the connection
    cs.close();
    conn.close();
   } 
   catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println ("\n*** SQLException caught ***\n" + ex.getMessage());}
  catch (Exception e) {System.out.println ("\n*** other Exception caught ***\n");}
  }
}
```

on compliling I get no errors but when I run it I get the following:

```
fsu% javac -cp "ojdbc6.jar" getemployees.java

fsu% java getemployees
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource
    at getemployees.main(getemployees.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't have any Java experience, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your classpath include the JDBC driver that you are trying to use?

Comment: On Linux: `java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. getemployees`. More details in the Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB  (or if you are using [Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB) )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name now showing *** SQLException caught ***
ORA-06550: line 1, column 23:
PLS-00302: component 'GET_EMPLOYEES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @JustinCave I don't follow you, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name now i added function declaration line in package creation code block, and I'm getting this error -----> *** SQLException caught ***
ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00905: object MYUSERID.PACKAGENAME is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored